# Summation of the n'th root of $2^i$

Tags: integration, summation

So I'm basically trying to write an explicit formula for this sum here:

Originally, I was asked to use the definition of an integral to evaluate: $$\int_{0}^{1} 2^x dx$$ so I rewrote this as a reimann sum to get:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {\frac {1}{n}}\sum_{i=1}^{n} 2^{\frac {i}{n}}$$

How do you evaluate that summation though? I'm completely lost on that. I tried to write it as a geometric series but that's not possible. It's not a p series either. How am I supposed to sum that?

Here is the way the professor did it but no work is shown for the summation at all...
[image]

Comment: Do you know the indefinite integral of $2^x$? Note that $2^x = e^{x \ln 2}$, so maybe definition of integral could mean a use of Fundamental theorem of calculus?

Comment: No it explicitly asked us to use reimann sums. It's even in the solutions. But no explanation was given as to how that sum was obtained.

Comment: Then it's best you post the intermediate result, or  the equality you don't understand in the answer. Surely there must be steps in the evaluation, right?

Comment: Well I edited my answer but it's not showing any work for the summation to be honest. It's just the limit work. I can do the limit but that summation has no explanation.

Comment: Fine, so the summation is a standard geometric series. Do you notice that? So the formula for geometric summation can be used. Do you need me to mention it explicitly? If so, then $\sum_{i=1}^n a^i = \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1} - 1$. Put in $a=2^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and simplify.

Comment: Geometric sum + L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: That's what I though but could you explain how it's a geometric series? I'm having trouble seeing it.

Comment: It is a geometric series, right You are summing the powers of $2^{\frac 1n}$ from $i=1$ to $n$. It looks  like a sequence where the ratio between consecutive terms is constant, right? Now the formula comes into play.

Comment: Thank you. I got it now. I just never saw that form of the geometric series below because the index always started at i=0 and not i=1. I forgot I can just subtract the previous term off to get the new sum.

Answer (score 1):

Take the Riemann summ approximation of order $n$ to the integral above:
$$\int_0^1 2^x 
\approx
\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{k=1}^n 2^{k/n}
=\frac{1}{n}
\sum_{k=1}^n (2^{1/n})^k.
$$
The sum on the right side is a geometric sum on $z=2^{1/n}$ which, as widely known, equals
$$
\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z }=\frac{1-(2^{1/n})^{n+1}}{1-2^{1/n} }.
$$
Substituted in the original equation gives
$$\int_0^1 2^x 
= \lim_{n\to\infty} 
\frac{1}{n}
\frac{1-(2^{1/n})^{n+1}}{1-2^{1/n} }. 
$$
Place $1=\lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{1/n}$ at the top of the fraction and the remaining part of the proof is explicit from here on in the image you shared.